# Error while building Selenium Specflow solution

Tags: c#, selenium, specflow

[image]

I get the error when I build my Solution,

"No overload for method 'OnScenarioStart' takes 1 arguments"

"Argument 2: cannot convert from 'string[]' to 'string'"

Specflow v2.4.0
Nunit v3.11.0

Please let me know if i am missing any reference?

Comment: How would we know if you've missed a reference without looking at your code? Please post more information.

Answer (score 0):

You have to regenerate the code-behind files of your feature files.
You can do this via saving every feature file separate, or there is an entry "Regenerate Feature Files" in the context menu of the project.

Answer (score 0):

Recently came across this doing an upgrade of SpecFlow, Selenium, and NUnit.
Open up your app.config file in your project, validate that your dependent assembly for SpecFlow has:

oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.4.0.0" newVersion="2.4.1"

Ensure you only have one instance of NUnit.Framework. In our case, we upgraded from 3.8.1 to 3.11.0, and there were two dependent assembly records in our app.config for both 3.8.1 and 3.11.0.

From there, I regenerated feature files in all of our projects, rebuilt the solution, and that has fixed the issue.